# Piecewise linear Interpolation between data points

Tags: interpolation

Is there some  sort of functionality built into *Mathematica* that will let me linearly interpolate between (x, y) pairs of data in an array?

Example: I have the two points (1, 10) and (2, 20), how can I find out what the interpolant at 1.5 would be?

Comment: Did searching for "interpolate" or "interpolation" in the documentation not give any results?

Comment: @rm-rf Yes, but I want `Interpolate[{Lena, Toady}]` and it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7):

What about using `Interpolation`?

```
f = Interpolation[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
f[1.5]
```

Comment: this method is significantly slower than matlab interp1 method

Answer (score 4):

Although not as elegant as halirutan's post, this helps alternatively,

```
f=Rescale[#,{1,2},{10,20}]&; 
f[1.5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as elegant as above approaches, but `Fit` can also be used. To try different shape functions:

```
data = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}};
trial = {{1, x}, {1, x, x^2}, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, {1, Sin[x]}, {1, Cos[x]}, 
         {1, Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {1, x, Exp[x]}, {1, x, x^2, Exp[x]}};
fits = Fit[data, #, x] & /@ trial;
x0 = 1.5;
Grid[Partition[
  Plot[#, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 230, 
     FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, 
        Grid[{{"f(x)=", #, SpanFromLeft}, {"f(", x0,")=", # /. x -> x0}}, 
            Spacings -> 0]}}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.1], Point[{x0, # /. x -> x0}]}, 
     ImagePadding -> {{30, 30}, {5, 50}}] & /@ fits, 3], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it has been missed that `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` can be used for "lerping". Here's halirutan's example as a one-liner:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}}, 1.5]
   15.
```